# Ubuntu 16.04 Running Hot (MSI GS70 stealth Pro)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, overheating, ubuntu-gnome, temperature

I just installed Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04, and its running unusually hot, above 60 C without any intensive applications running. In windows it sits closer to 50 C when nothing intesnive is running. In the past, this often occurred before I installed the nvidia drivers and the computer was using intel integrated graphics, but I already installed those and it still seems to be running hot. Here's my lspci output if it helps

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

Let me know any other information that might be helpful in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** After some messing around I've noticed the temperature drops substantially when I unplug the power cable from my laptop. Is it possible Ubuntu is someone how mishandling the incoming power? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the discrepancy in temperature comes from the fact that the nvidia drivers in windows automatically switch between intel integrated graphics and the nvidia graphics card based on what the computer is running. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any way to do this in linux (bumblebee is a rough solution). However, the graphics device can be switched manually under nvidia-x-server settings by changing the prime profile.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer by clicking on the gray checkmark next to it; that way other people can see your question has been resolved